# Access STDIN of child process without capturing STDOUT or STDERR

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9, ruby-2.0

In Ruby, is it possible to prevent the standard input of a spawned child process from being attached to the terminal without having to capture the `STDOUT` or `STDERR` of that same process?

- Backticks and x-strings (`` `...` ``, `%x{...}`) don't work because they capture STDIN.
- `Kernel#system` doesn't work because it leaves STDIN attached to the
  terminal (which intercepts signals like `^C` and prevents them from
  reaching my program, which is what I'm trying to avoid).
- `Open3` doesn't work because its methods capture either `STDOUT` or
  both `STDOUT` and `STDERR`.

So what should I use?

Comment: Why don't you take the time to show some examples of what you are trying to do. Don't make us guess or try to envision your code. That's a waste of time. See http://sscce.org/

Comment: @theTinMan I don't see how that's applicable in this situation. I don't have some piece of code that's broken that I'm trying to fix, I have a specific question about Ruby's API that want answered.

I've already listed three examples that DON'T work. Do you want me to put those examples in context and demonstrate that they don't work? :confused:

Comment: What is it about capturing STDOUT and STDERR as `open3` does, that you want to avoid? If they are *not* captured and managed by parent process, where do you wish them to go?

Comment: @NeilSlater I want them to go wherever the parent process's `STDOUT` and `STDERR` are going; just like with `Kernel#system`.

Comment: The parent process has STDOUT wired to the TTY device by default. Redirecting the child's STDOUT using `> /dev/tty` will act like the parent, keeping the parent from seeing or capturing the output. You can use `| tee /dev/stdout /dev/tty` to return output to the parent and output to the terminal/tty device at the same time. The OS's `tty` command can be useful too. The /dev devices have to be used carefully but some are handy for this sort of trick. This isn't a Ruby thing, it's a *nix thing.

Comment: Also look at the /dev/fd devices. http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=99706&seqNum=15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’re on a platform that supports it, you could do this with [`pipe`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-c-pipe), [`fork`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Process.html#method-c-fork) and [`exec`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-exec):

```ruby
# create a pipe
read_io, write_io = IO.pipe

child = fork do
  # in child

  # close the write end of the pipe
  write_io.close

  # change our stdin to be the read end of the pipe
  STDIN.reopen(read_io)

  # exec the desired command which will keep the stdin just set
  exec 'the_child_process_command'
end

# in parent

# close read end of pipe
read_io.close

# write what we want to the pipe, it will be sent to childs stdin
write_io.write "this will go to child processes stdin"
write_io.close

Process.wait child
```

Comment: Hmm. That solution is pretty platform specific, but it does do what I want. Too bad Windows doesn't support fork or exec. :( It doesn't seem like there is any platform independent solution though so I'll go with this for now.