# ruby: running a command from a forked child process

Tags: python, ruby, ssh, io, fabric

I've the following snippet of code:

```
job1 = fork do
    ret = `some_bash_script_running_python_fabric_task`
end

Process.detach(job1)
```

This code is aimed at daemonizing a process, so the parent exits while child keeps running in background.

I get as a result a python exception stating `termios.error: (5, 'Input/output error')`.

I figured out that avoiding the parent process to exit fixes the situation, like this:

```
job1 = fork do
    ret = `some_bash_script_running_python_fabric_task`
end

sleep 30
```

Someone may help ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: OS? I ran an example with `sleep 10 ; ls` script in linux console without any problem.

Comment: OS is linux. the script is actually a fabric script which runs an ssh command over a remote machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out being a matter of redirecting stdin from parent to child process.

See below:

[Perl's backticks/system giving "tcsetattr: Input/output error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997387/perls-backticks-system-giving-tcsetattr-input-output-error)

[Access STDIN of child process without capturing STDOUT or STDERR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18469773/access-stdin-of-child-process-without-capturing-stdout-or-stderr)

This is the solution:

```
read_io, write_io = IO.pipe
job1 = fork do
    write_io.close
    STDIN.reopen(read_io)

    puts `fab example`
end

Process.detach(job1)
read_io.close
write_io.close
```